# Como altero para required um input usando Angular Material?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

De que forma posso setar como obrigatórios campos para preenchimento apos setar escolha no radio como fixa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Codigo**

**html**

```
 <span>
        <label>Atividade Fixa:  </label>
        <mat-radio-group  name="atividade_fixa">
            <mat-radio-button value="true">Sim</mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button value="false">Não</mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
    </span>
```

e

```
<span>
    <mat-form-field style="width:100px;">
    <input matInput [matDatepickerFilter]="myFilter" [matDatepicker]="dpDataLimite" [min]="data?data:minDate" placeholder="Data Limite" [(ngModel)]="dataLimite"                             name="dpDataLimite">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dpDataLimite">
    </mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #dpDataLimite></mat-datepicker>
     </mat-form-field>
    </span>
```

Comment: Deve ter uma forma mais bonita, mas essa foi a que consegui pensar agora: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drac5s?file=app%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solução proposta:**

```
<span>
        <label>Atividade Fixa:  </label>
        <mat-radio-group  name="atividade_fixa">
            <mat-radio-button (change)="requiredTime=true" value="true">Sim</mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button (change)="requiredTime=false" value="false">Não</mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
</span>
<br>
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput #inpicker [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" [required]="requiredTime">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**Descrição da solução:**

Adicionei (change) ao radio button de forma que quando selecionado vai setar um valor para   
Minha proposta é torna esse input required.

Comment: Coloque uma explicação do que você fez, para ajudar a próxima pessoa que estiver com o mesmo problema que o seu :)